# How to download a d3js tree as SVG file and fill the viewBox

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, namespaces, viewbox

I have a D3JS tree and managed to download it as an SVG file.  I have used to following code to enable the download:

```
   $('#download-SVG').click(function() {
    var dl = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(dl); // This line makes it work in Firefox.
    dl.setAttribute("href", svgDataURL(svg.node())); //function svgDataURL expects a node
    dl.setAttribute("download", "hawashim.svg");
    dl.click();
   });
```

I was not able to figure out how to use the createElementsNS and setAttributeNS functions as suggested by [Namespaces_Crash_Course](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Namespaces_Crash_Course)
to use DOM2 instead of DOM1.  Therefore I use parse and replace to insert the namespace and other attributes into the svg document (which is not ideal) by using the following code:

```
// A data URL can also be generated from an existing SVG element.
   function svgDataURL(svg) {
    var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);

    //parse the svg data and add name spaces (the opening svg tag).
    if(!svgAsXML.match(/^<svg[^>]+xmlns="http\:\/\/www\.w3\.org\/2000\/svg"/)){
        svgAsXML = svgAsXML.replace(/^<g/, '<svg');
    }

    //parse the svg data and add name spaces (the closing svg tag)
    if(!svgAsXML.match(/^<\/svg[^>]/)){
        svgAsXML = svgAsXML.replace(/<\/g><\/g>/, '<\/g><\/svg>');
    }
    var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
    return dataURL;
   }
```

A snippet from my .SVG file:

```
<svg viewBox=" -2500 -420 12000 10000"  width= "100%" height= "auto" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" .... </svg>
```

Currently I insert the "viewBox" and "aspect ratios" manually in the file, however the resulting graph does not fill the viewBox no matter what values I insert.

I have three questions:

1. How do I convert the above code to use NS equivalent of the functions I used?
2. What should I use to make the tree graph fill the box?
3. Is it possible to fill the viewBox dynamically depending on the size of the expanded tree?

Comment: presumably you need to adjust the viewBox values (make them smaller) till the data does fill the viewport.

Comment: @RobertLongson There are approx. 9000 nodes in the tree and on average about 100 nodes are expanded by the users.  If I reduce the size of the viewBox, the tree would look bigger but get truncated when the svg file is viewed or printed.

Comment: in that case you need to use different viewBox values for your different use cases I suppose.